# Java 8: Merging two Lists containing objects by key

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists:

```
List<Server> servers1 = new ArrayList<>();
Server s1 = new Server("MyServer");
s1.setAttribute1("Attribute1");
servers1.add(s1);

List<Server> servers2 = new ArrayList<>();
Server s2 = new Server("MyServer");
s2.setAttribute2("Attribute2");
servers2.add(s2);
```

`servers1` contains servers with a `name` and an `attribute1` (but no `attribute2`).
`servers2` contains servers with a `name` and an `attribute2` (but no `attribute1`).

```
public class Server {
   private String name;
   private String attribute1;
   private String attribute2;

   public Server(String name) { 
       this.name = name;
       this.attribute1 = "";
       this.attribute2 = "";
   }

   //Getters & Setters

}
```

Does anyone know how I can merge these two lists to one list containing
each `Server` only once (by `name`) but with both attributes?

There are servers which only exist in one or the other list.
The final list should contain all servers.

```
    List<Server> servers1 = new ArrayList<>();
    Server s1 = new Server("MyServer");
    s1.setAttribute1("Attribute1");

    Server s2 = new Server("MyServer2");
    s2.setAttribute1("Attribute1.2");

    servers1.add(s1);
    servers1.add(s2);

    List<Server> servers2 = new ArrayList<>();
    Server s3 = new Server("MyServer");
    s3.setAttribute2("Attribute2");

    Server s4 = new Server("MyServer3");
    s4.setAttribute2("Attribute2.2");

    servers2.add(s3);
    servers2.add(s4);
```

should result in:

[Server [name=MyServer,  attribute1=Attribute1,   attribute2=Attribute2],

Server [name=MyServer2, attribute1=Attribute1.2, attribute2=]]

Server [name=MyServer3, attribute1=,             attribute2=Attribute2.2]]

**//SOLUTION** (thx everybody for the help!)

```
Map<String, Server> serverMap1 = Stream.concat(servers1.stream(), servers2.stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Server::getName, Function.identity(), 
            (server1, server2) -> {
                server1.setAttribute2(server2.getAttribute2()); 
                return server1; 
            }));
```

Comment: Create a map of `name` to `Server` from `servers1` and then fill the missing `attribute2` from `servers2` looking up the server in the map by name. Try to write some code on your own.

Comment: If that is the entirety of your `Server` class, how do the entities in either `List` have any values for `name`, `attribute1` or `attribute2`.  If this is not the entire class, please include constructor(s)

Comment: Does the two lists contain always the same servers or exist servers that will not be merged?

Comment: Good question. There are servers which won't be merged.
In the end I need all servers and if they can be merged, the should.

Comment: I tried the same thing. I am not getting data for 2nd lists objects not present in 1st list. In this case for server3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert each list to map and merge it (I use Lombok to not write boilerplate code):

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class Server {
    private String name;
    private String attribute1;
    private String attribute2;
}

public class ServerMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Server> servers1 = Arrays.asList(
                new Server("name1", "attr1.1", null),
                new Server("name2", "attr1.2", null));

        List<Server> servers2 = Arrays.asList(
                new Server("name1", null, "attr2.1"),
                new Server("name2", null, "attr2.2"));

        Map<String, Server> serverMap1 = servers1.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Server::getName, Function.identity()));
        Map<String, Server> serverMap2 = servers2.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Server::getName, Function.identity()));

        serverMap1.keySet().forEach(key -> serverMap1.merge(key,
                serverMap2.get(key),
                (server1, server2) -> {
                    server1.setAttribute2(server2.getAttribute2());
                    return server1;
                }));


        System.out.println(serverMap1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re doing too much work, collecting into two maps to do two map lookups for each server. You can remove the `serverMap2` entirely and just do `servers2.forEach(s -> serverMap1.merge(s.getName(), s, /* the same merge function as before */));`

Comment: If you are confident that the keys are unique, you can do it even in a single Stream operation: `serverMap1 = Stream.concat(servers1.stream(), servers2.stream())   .collect(Collectors.toMap( Server::getName, Function.identity(), /* the same merge function as before */));`

Comment: @Holger I would suggest converting your comment into answer, it looks like only 'elegant' stream based answer.

Comment: servers which don't exist in servers1 should be in the final list as well (even if it only contains one attribute then)

Comment: @Robin, see second comment of Holger

Comment: @Holger @DmitryGorkovets , this doesn't work for me 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key`, since the map would have the name as key twice.

Comment: @Robin, have you added merge function from my example to Holger's version?

Answer (score 2):

For each server in servers1 find a matching server2 in servers2 and set the missing attribute of the first one to correct attribute else if there is no matching server by name simply return null. Also note that this implementation will return only the list of servers name contained in servers1.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
private class Server {
   private String name;
   private String attribute1;
   private String attribute2;
}

List<Server> completServersInfo = servers1.stream()
     .map((server1 -> {
        Server matchingServer = servers2.stream()
           .filter(server2 -> server2.name.equals(server1.name))
           .findFirst()
           .orElse(null);
        server1.setAttribute2(matchingServer.attribute2);
        return server1;
     }))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: if you're confident same key exists on both lists

Map<String, Server> serverMap1 = servers1.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Server::getName, Function.identity()));
        
        servers2
        .forEach(key->serverMap1.get(key.getName()).setAttribute2(key.getAttribute2()));
        
        System.out.println(serverMap1);

Comment: the same key doesn't need to exist in both lists.
If it doesn't, the server should appear in the final list as it is (with missing arguments)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a map to do it? The key of the map would be the name of the server and the value of the map is the object `Server`.

```
Map<String, Server> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Server s : servers1) {
    map.put(s.getName(), s);
}
for (Server s : servers2) {
    String key = s.getName();
    if (map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.get(key).setAttribute2(s.getAttribute2());
    } else {
        map.put(key, s);
    }
}
List<Server> servers = new ArrayList<>(map.values()); // or other impl.
```

Comment: Love this approach. Very efficient even when processing hundreds of thousands of records.